# Download File with Http Request and UTF-8

Tags: java, http, https

I wrote a code like this.

```
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();


        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");


        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();



            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new       FileOutputStream("C:\\aaaa\\ww.csv");

                int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
```

The code works well.I send request and ı can download the csv file into my computer.But ı want to know that if the csv file have turkish characters(ş,ğ,ı,ç) can ı download the csv with that characters.

or what can ı do for that characters to see them in csv file.

Comment: Did you try it with turkish characters? What happens? Is there a difference between requesting the document with a browser and your code? What are the values for the content type and character encoding headers in the response? What kind of server is it? Do you own the server?

Answer (score 0):

The server sends you a stream of bytes and you just save the byte stream on your disk, so you don't need to worry about characters.